# Passing variables between module and form

Tags: excel, vba

I have a module and a public variable declared:

```
Public przekazanie As Double
```

Next i want to take this variable from the module and later to use it inside my userform in the following way:

```
TextBox8.value = "DPPK" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(przekazanie, "00000")
```

However in the form the variable przekazanie is equal to 0.

Why my user form does not read arguments from the module?

Value of przekazanie is being set when a CommandButton is clicked

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

przekazanie = 2



Load Matryca
Matryca.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: `TextBox8.value = "DPPK" & Format$(przekazanie, "00000")`

Comment: Do you set its value?

Comment: Please provide the full code where you set the value of `przekazanie`, without it is impossible for us to tell where you've gone wrong.

Comment: If you have the `Public przekazanie As Double` in a regular module, the variable should work. Where is the command button you are opening the userform located?

Comment: Command button is located inside a worksheet and code to this button is as well located inside the worksheet code (As appropriate).

Comment: I did what you say you did and the variable value did =2 when I stepped through the code. What is happening with  `Load Matryca` ?

Comment: Load matryca is simply loading and presenting the user form.

Comment: You should add `Option Explicit` at the top of your userform, which will highlight the fact that your variable is not declared. If you want to use the variable the way you're doing it, you need to move it in an actual module, not the sheet module.

Comment: Great It works!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct. If you run the function CommandButton1_Click(), everything should work as you expect it. But if you only run Matryca_Initialize() in your TextBox8 will be shown whatever VBA has stored for your global variable przekazanie (which is zero, when przekazanie did not see a value assigned to it before.)
So my proposed solution is not to only run Matryca_Initialize(), which I assume you were doing.